# How can I get the date/time at which the item was last published in Tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

How can I get the date/time at which the item was last published.

I tried to create object for PublishInfoData inorder to use PublishedAt.

```
  PublishInfoData pobj = csClient.Read(pageTCMID, readoptions) as PublishInfoData;
```

But this gives error like cannot convert IdentifiableObjectData to PublishInfoData.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will give you all publish info:

```
csClient.GetListPublishInfo(pageTCMID);
```

And then you have to select the latest:

```
var publishInfo = csClient.GetListPublishInfo(pageTCMID);
var lastPublishedAt = publishInfo.OrderByDescending(pi => pi.PublishedAt).First().PublishedAt;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. On trying this it says InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements.

Comment: That means that `publishInfo.OrderByDescending(pi => pi.PublishedAt)` didn't return anything and thus `.First()` then fails. Most likely your item hasn't been published yet.

Answer (score 0):

I add this Powershell code for the record to get the last published date of a page

```
Set-TridionCoreServiceSettings sdswpap004 2013-SP1
$client = Get-TridionCoreServiceClient

Write-Output "Getting the title"
$pageTitle = Get-TridionItem -Id "tcm:30-7386-64" | Select-Object Title
Write-Output $pageTitle

$publishInfo = $client.GetListPublishInfo("tcm:30-7386-64")



if ($publishInfo) {
    Write-Output "Getting the last pablished date: "
    Write-Output $publishInfo.PublishedAt | Out-String
}
```